# How to use an external javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to build a webpage using html and an external javascript file. The javascript file is named "main.js" and is in the same directory as the html file. I'd like to call a function from the javascript file inside the html file.

The function is linked to a button as is called using the following line:

```
<button onclick="myFunc()">Click Me</button>
```

If I use the script tag and embed the javascript inside the html file it works fine, with format:

```
<script> 
funtion myFunc(){

//Code here
}
</script>
```

When I put this function in a separate main.js file and then call it using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
```

the button does nothing. Is there a syntax I'm missing?

ADDITION edit:

Here's and edit to hopefully make the question more clear. I am a beginner in javascript so apologies if I'm asking in an unclear way. Below is the full javascript function I'm using to test in my html file. It's from w3 schools and I'm just using it to test. The function moves a square from the top left of a larger square to the bottom right.

```
<script>
    
    function myMove() {
    var id = null;
    var elem = document.getElementById('myAnimation');
    var pos = 350;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame,10);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 0){
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
        pos--;
        elem.style.bottom = pos +'px';
        elem.style.right = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

When directly embedded in the html code, it works just fine. When I put this exact function in an external javascript file, named 'test.js', and then include the reference to that file in the html, so the body of the html file is:

```
<script type="module" src="/test.js"></script>

<a href="../index.html"><button1>home</button1></a><br>

<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
<div id ="myContainer">
<div id ="myAnimation"></div>
</div>
```

For reference, the javascript file looks like this:

```
import './style.css'


function myMove() {
  var id = null;
  var elem = document.getElementById('myAnimation');
  var pos = 350;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame,10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0){
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos--;
      elem.style.bottom = pos +'px';
      elem.style.right = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing happens. Does this make the question more clear?

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: If I use the script tag and embed the javascript inside the html file it works fine, with format:" — No, it doesn't. The `function` keyword is missing.

Comment: The most likely reason (assuming that the scripts are identical) is that the URL is wrong. Use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to debug it. Make sure you aren't getting a 404 Not Found or other error state for the request.

Comment: The next most likely reason would give a fairly obvious error message about an unexpected `<` causing a syntax error in the browser's developer tools console.

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it worked for me(the files are separate)

```js
function myFunc() {
    alert("hello")
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Testing... </h1>
        <button onclick="myFunc()"> Click Me </button>

        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Its also a good idea to be running your code in a simple python server.
[Python Simple Server Setup](https://linuxconfig.org/running-a-simple-http-web-server-with-one-terminal-command-and-python)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).